# Add dynamic dropdown list (populate from db) in XML file for Joomla authentication Plugin

Tags: json, api, plugins, joomla

I am implement a Joomla 3.7 customer user plugin and I have the following issue:

I want to have a drop-down list type plugin parameter where the option values are not statically provided in the plugin xml file, but they are populated dynamically from php code that grabs them from another extension via some JSONRPC api calls.

Please help me How to achieve this.
 Thank you

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/SQL_form_field_type

```
<field
name="title"
type="sql"
default="10"
label="Select an article"
query="SELECT id AS value, title FROM #__content"
/>
```

Comment: I want to ask one more question This is perfect for data is populated from database.But I want Is this possible to populate dynamically data from third party API (json rpc methods)